# How to scrape a news website entirely asynchronously?

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to scrape a news website. The whole task can be divided into the following tasks:

1. GET-querying and getting a response in the form of an html document containing links to the news articles, as well as a URL to the next similar document (resembling a singly linked list).
2. Querying and scraping each of the news articles.
3. Returning to the first step, but with a query for the URL we obtained earlier.

Obviously, the initializing query from the first step will be blocking in any case, but how to concurrently implement all subsequent such queries and again make up asyncio.tasks from the received news URLs? That is, to asynchronously execute the first step while scraping news articles, with getting the right values (urls, data_next; see below) from the coroutine. In the code below is the situation at the moment, where the first step is performed using a blocking call.

```
tasks = []
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    urls, data_next = get_urls(TAG_URL.format('economy'))
    while condition:
        for url in urls:
            task = asyncio.create_task(parse_page(url, session, f))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        urls, data_next = get_urls(data_next)
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking, or what's in `get_urls`, but I guess what you mean is you want to add the `get_urls` call to the async task you are creating, rather than wait until `asyncio.gather` finishes.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, sounds like it is. `get_urls()` returns a list of news' urls and a url to the next such page. I'd like the script to work uninterruptedly, with `tasks` list being updated continuously with `parse_page()` coroutines.

Comment: So where you `create_task`, create another which extracts more URLs, or include that functionality in the task you already create.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad/vague, so I'll answer in an equally broad fashion.

For use cases like this, a common approach is to use a **queue** of URLs to scrape that is shared among multiple **workers**. In your case one option would be to have each worker coroutine both *take* urls from the queue and *put* new URLs it finds back into it.

Here is a rudimentary example demo of such a setup: (works *as is*)

```py
from asyncio import CancelledError, Queue, gather, run, sleep
from random import random


async def scrape(url: str) -> list[str]:
    await sleep(random())
    ...  # actually process the scraped data
    return ["http://example.com/abc", "http://example.com/xyz"]


async def worker(q: Queue, i: int) -> None:
    while True:
        url = await q.get()
        print(f"worker {i} scraping {url}")
        new_urls = await scrape(url)
        for new_url in new_urls:
            q.put_nowait(new_url)


async def main() -> None:
    entry_url = "http://example.com/"
    q = Queue()
    q.put_nowait(entry_url)
    workers = (worker(q, i) for i in range(5))
    try:
        await gather(*workers)
    except CancelledError:
        return


run(main())
```

In this example, I used a fixed number of five workers, but you can construct a more elaborate setup with some sort of controller that can increase or decrease the number of workers dynamically as a function of whatever parameters are important to you.

It also would likely make sense to keep track of the URLs that were already processed so as to avoid putting those into the queue, in case they are encountered again at some later point in time.